# How to access response returned by web API after a successful upload?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, filepond

I have checked the documentations but not anywhere I can find any details to the requirement I need.

Here's a web API resource it's called when uploading which returns a json of its filename and content.

```
    [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        try
        {
            var stamp = FileHelper.FormatShortDateForfilename(DateTime.Now, true);
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            if (file.Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("No file uploaded.");

            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
            fileName = $"[{stamp}] {fileName}";
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, fileName);

            var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            if (!acceptables.Contains(ext.Replace(".", "")))
                throw new Exception($"Only {String.Join("-", acceptables).ToUpper()} files are acceptables.");

            using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyTo(stream);
            }

            dynamic upldData = new JObject();
            upldData.filename = fileName;
            upldData.Content = "........";
            return Json(upldData.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return Json("Upload Failed: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And here's from my ReactJS script where I will need to access that response.

```
<FilePond ref={ref => this.pond = ref}
                server="api/imports"
                labelIdle={'Drag & Drop your CSV file here or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'}
                checkValidity={true}
                acceptedFileTypes={['application/vnd.ms-excel']}
                onupdatefiles={fs => {
                    this.setState({ hasFile: fs.length });
                }}
                onremovefile={(fs) => {
                    this.setState({ hasFile: fs && fs.length });
                }}
                onaddfile={fs => { this.setState({ hasFile: false }) }}
                onprocessfile={(err, file) => {
                    console.log('FilePond ready for use', err, file);
                    console.log('test', file.serverId);
                }}
            />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spend some time to figure out what is going on here. 
This is the main functionality for creating requests inside filePond.

```
const createProcessorFunction = (apiUrl = '', action, name) => {
  // custom handler (should also handle file, load, error, progress and abort)
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    return (...params) => action(name, ...params);
  }

  // no action supplied
  if (!action || !isString(action.url)) {
    return null;
  }

  // internal handler
  return (file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort) => {
    // set onload hanlder
    const ondata = action.ondata || (fd => fd);
    const onload = action.onload || (res => res);
    const onerror = action.onerror || (res => null);

    // no file received
    if (!file) return;

    // create formdata object
    var formData = new FormData();

    // add metadata under same name
    if (isObject(metadata)) {
      formData.append(name, JSON.stringify(metadata));
    }

    // Turn into an array of objects so no matter what the input, we can handle it the same way
    (file instanceof Blob ? [{ name: null, file }] : file).forEach(item => {
      formData.append(
        name,
        item.file,
        item.name === null ? item.file.name : `${item.name}${item.file.name}`
      );
    });

    // send request object
    const request = sendRequest(ondata(formData), apiUrl + action.url, action);
    request.onload = xhr => {
      load(
        createResponse(
          'load',
          xhr.status,
          onload(xhr.response),
          xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()
        )
      );
    };

    request.onerror = xhr => {
      error(
        createResponse(
          'error',
          xhr.status,
          onerror(xhr.response) || xhr.statusText,
          xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()
        )
      );
    };

    request.ontimeout = createTimeoutResponse(error);
    request.onprogress = progress;
    request.onabort = abort;

    // should return request
    return request;
  };
};
```

As you see You can pass a function or an object as a value for `server` property. 
There are some methods like `onload`, `onerror` and `ondata` which you can check and try to find the solution for your issue. Or just pass custom function and do your request inside of it like

```
<FilePond server={(...args) => this.handleUploadRequest(...args)} />
```

I hope it will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can access the response in the `server.process.onload` callback, make sure you still return the unique file id in said callback.

A custom process method will also work, you can find more info here:
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#advanced

Answer (score 1):

this is how I did in angular

```
pondOptions = {
    class: 'my-filepond',
    multiple: true,
    labelIdle: 'Drop files here or click to upload',
    acceptedFileTypes: 'image/jpeg, image/png',
    server: {
      url: environment.base_url + environment.upload_file_url,
      process: {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Token ' + window.localStorage.getItem('USER_TOKEN') || null
        },
        onload: (response) => {this.UPLOAD_FILES.push(response)}, // saving response in global array
      }
    }
  };
```